# Extract text inside cdata tag using XSLT

Tags: xslt, cdata

I have the following XML with a cdata tag that I would like to extract the text from?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<cus:TestData xmlns:cus="http://test.namespace.com/data">
<![CDATA[testValue]]></cus:TestData >
```

How can I achieve this in XSLT?

I was briefly trying with the following

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        "<xsl:value-of select="/*/Name"/>"
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working

Also the XML doesn't also have the same prefix or namespace, it changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an issue with CData. Your XSLT is currently looking for an element called `Name`, under the root element, which does not exist in your XML. If your XML source is the one you are actually using, you can just do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="/*"/>
```

But supposing your XML looked like this...

```
<cus:TestData xmlns:cus="http://test.namespace.com/data">
   <cus:Name><![CDATA[testValue]]></cus:Name>
</cus:TestData>
```

Then, you would need to account for the namespace in your XSLT, as `Name` is in a namespace in your XML, but your XSLT is currently looking for a `Name` element in no namespace.

Something like this would do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:c="http://test.namespace.com/data">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      "<xsl:value-of select="/*/c:Name"/>"
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, the prefixes don't need to match, but the namespace URI does.

If the namespace URI could actually vary, you could do something like this instead...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      "<xsl:value-of select="/*/*[local-name() = 'Name']"/>"
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried your last solution on http://xslttest.appspot.com/ and I just get a blank string not the value inside the CDATA tag?

Comment: Apologies I forgot to update the node. This is working. Thank you very much

Comment: Is there anyway I could get this to always take he first node after the xml tag?

Comment: If you mean the `<?xml ` declaration, then the first solution `<xsl:value-of select="/*"/>` would do it.